# C# ServiceBase OnPowerEvent BatteryLow

Tags: c#, windows, service

I've created a very simple service to save to a log the power events as they occur, for the moment, so I can understand what the events look like when the service receives them.

Most of them come through correctly and make sense, the event I'm missing is BatteryLow, I've had the PC run from 100% to completely flat and I get all of the other events.

Is there something special I need to be aware of for the BatteryLow event?

TIA.

Comment: The documentation says "The system also broadcasts this event **when remaining battery power slips below the threshold specified by the user**"

Comment: Hi Oguz, you're right, it does say that in the docs but I'm not seeing it occur during real-world testing.

Comment: What I mean is, did you set this treshold? I don't know this API well, but when reading this sentence it is interpreted like you need to set some treshold value first and this event (BatteryLow) will be triggered when the power goes below that.

Comment: Thanks Oguz, I hadn't though of investigating the problem from that angle. I had taken it to mean that whenever Windows displays the "Battery Low power" warning across the screen then my service would be alerted too. That's what I was hoping (or expecting) but not getting.